# Adding subviews to the UIScrollView mess up autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a view set up like this:
[image]
Here goes label, thin view to represent a separation line, scrollview to the bottom of the screen, one view, that represent blur and last view with button. Blur view and button views lays over scroll view and don't change positions while scrolling.

Also i have custom view, that i created in separate xib. So i am trying to add n of them in scrollview programmatically.

I do it like so:

```
let tmp:NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("sourceButton", owner: self, options: nil)
self.button = tmp.objectAtIndex(0) as? UIButton
self.scrollView.addSubview(button!)
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.contentSize.height + 50);
```

and in viewDidLayoutSubviews() i change the frame:

```
self.button!.frame = CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width*0.05, 20, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width*0.4, 100)
```

The problem is that when i add more than one of my custom views top label goes off the screen and all ui moves top slightly.

With one customView
[image]

With two customViews
[image]

Between viewWillLayoutSubviews and viewDidLayoutSubviews frames changes like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i added height constraint on top label and everything workes. But i am still interested why 2 custom views messed things up and 1 custom view did not.

Comment: because ultimately after giving all 4 side constraints you have to give width and height to the inner content also. it was ok for one view but you  did not managed height of 2 views.